# Changing South Migration Directory

Tags: python, django, django-orm, django-south

How do you change the location where South looks for an app's migrations?

By default, South assumes an app's migrations are in /migrations. However, I've migrated the model of a third-party package which is installed at /usr/local/lib/python-2.6/dist-packages/, so South is looking for migrations there, instead of the location of my custom codebase.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In settings.py:

```
SOUTH_MIGRATION_MODULES = {
    'books': 'myproject.app_name.migrations',
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be great if we could specify one location (with eventually subfolders) for all 3rd party packages ?